# PHPUnit and Mongo with Phactory

Tags: mongodb, phpunit, phactory

I am new to Unit testing and trying to use Phactory with Mongo, but when I run the test I keep getting the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mongo' not found in /vagrant/Test/user/LoginTest.php on line 19
```

I know Mongo is installed because when I pull up the site it works, but for some reason PHPUnit isn't recognizing it.

I feel I am missing a step.  Do I need to install the Mongo extension locally, or do I need to include the location in a config file somewhere?

Comment: Make sure you have a Bootstrap file configured inside your Test folder. http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html PHPUnit needs to know what to include

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure Mongo is installed as a module in the command line version of PHP?

Do a quick run of `php -i` and have a look at the output (which is `phpinfo()` without fancy formatting) or `php -m` for a list of modules. If the Mongo extension does not show up, you have to install it.

Also note that the `Mongo` class has been deprecated. You'd probably update to using `MongoClient`.